# JetBrains Terraform and HCL plugin not working properly with AWS Provider v4.0+

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm running:
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-221.6008.13, built on July 18, 2022

I have installed:
Terraform and HCL
JetBrains 221.6008.13

It seems that this plugin is not respecting the new AWS Provider v4+ constructs.  I've found several examples so far in our existing code (most notably while trying to refactor the S3 deprecated resource definitions).

Here is some example code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example-bucket" {
  bucket                = "example"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "example-bucket_lifecycle_configuration" {
  bucket                = aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket
  rule {
    id     = "${aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket}-lifecycle_configuration"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days                         = 7
      expired_object_delete_marker = false
    }

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      noncurrent_days = 1
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "example-bucket_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_logging" "example-bucket_logging" {

  bucket                = aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket
  target_bucket         = "log-bucket"
  target_prefix         = "${aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket}/"

}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "example-bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" {
  bucket                = aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      sse_algorithm = "AES256"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "example-bucket_acl" {
  bucket                = aws_s3_bucket.example-bucket.bucket
  acl                   = "private"
}
```

[Code as displayed by IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZYdZ.png)

We see that the IDE flags several blocks as 'Unknown Block Type' when they are actually valid (and process correctly through Terraform with the AWS Provider v4.22.0)

I can't find a way to change the version that the plugin should use, and it seems that it is updated fairly regularly (Latest release was 7/9/2022).  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you go to `Help` -> `Check for Updates`? It will tell you if there are updates to any of your plugins when you do that.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB.  I did do that, and am running the latest version of the plugin.

Comment: The plugin's `.jar` file seems to have schema information for some popular providers, including the `hashicorp/aws` provider, embedded inside it. Some metadata in that schema file for release 222.3345.93 says it was generated with v4.18.0 of the provider, but I'm just peeping in there with no prior knowledge of how this works so I don't know if that version number is trustworthy. In any event, it seems like a particular release of the plugin has a snapshot of a particular provider version locked in and may not be able to fully validate configuration intended for a different version.